# Why might the UTF combine cities into Megalopolises?

Tags: cities

So, in the late part of the 22nd century all the countries and people of earth combined to form the United Terran Federation. Its capital is in DC, but each former country has its own capital in its former capital city. The UTF is overseen by a High Councilor and his administrators, and they make a decision about what to do with Earth. They combine each region into one city, e.g. East Asian Megalopolis, West Coast Megalopolis, South American Megalopolis. My question is, what is a plausible explanation for why they do this?

Comment: All Asia in a city? Who cultivate crops?

Comment: @L.Dutch: They have set aside a bunch of land for crop cultivation, and there are green houses in the city

Comment: So the cities does not combine, like they do today, they just move all people from Boston and Atlanta, for example, to DC?

Comment: @Alexander: No, No

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is everyone forced to live in one place or is this just a legal trick/a way to organize a government? To me it sounds as if this is just about administration or something? The definition of what a city is differs from country to country btw.

Comment: In accordance with [our policy on high-concept questions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/6986), I am voting to close this as _too broad_. If you can determine a sufficient edit, I would also suggest better defining what you consider this society to look like.

Comment: I suggest having a read of the manga One Punch Man. There the cities are combined into Megalopolises so that security can be concentrated into a much smaller distance, rather than spread out. This is of course due to monsters, and doesn't mean that you will be safe, just that someone will respond quicker as there will be less distance to cover if compared to your normal city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Maybe they do it for administration purposes

It’s easier to control a large singular city than a bunch of individual artists cities, maybe that’s why.